# How to mock history.listen?

Tags: react-router, enzyme, browser-history, history.js

`history.js`

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

In my `.js` this is how I am using `history.listen`

```
import history from './history';
```

The following in the constructor:

```
history.listen(location => {
  if (location.pathname === '/second') {
    this.setState({
      pathStep: 1,
    });
  } else if (location.pathname === '/') {
    this.setState({
      pathStep: 0,
    });
  }
});
```

Now I am struggling to have a valid test for that:

```
    I tried to do the following:
    jest.mock('./history', () => ({
      listen: () => () => {
        '/second';
      },
    }));

    it('changes activeStep when called', () => {
      expect(component.state().pathStep).toBe(1);
    });
```

But even adding a `console.log` after `history.listen(location => {` I am not reaching my `history.listen`. So I am curious what I am doing wrong

I also tried adding `spyOn` to `history.listen`, but keen to hear what is the best practice for this specific test

Comment: Can you update your question with more of the actual code?  It looks like that code exists in a method of a React component, and it looks like `history` would be the result of calling `createBrowserHistory` from [`history`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history), can you confirm?

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors Hey! I updated the question with adding extra details how my history.js file looks like, how I import it and where I have the the history.listen

Comment: Sorry, I got busy and it took me a bit to get back to this.  I added an answer below that shows how to get the callback function from `history.listen` so you can call it directly with whatever you want and verify that your component responds the correct way, enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

If you mock `history.listen`, you can *get the callback that your component passes to it*.

Then, you can *call the callback directly* to verify that your component responds correctly.

Here is a complete working example:

history.js

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

code.js

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import history from './history';

export class SimpleComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = { pathStep: 0 };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.unlisten = history.listen(location => {
      if (location.pathname === '/second') {
        this.setState({
          pathStep: 1,
        });
      } else if (location.pathname === '/') {
        this.setState({
          pathStep: 0,
        });
      }
    });
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unlisten();
  }
  render() { return null; }
}
```

code.test.js

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import history from './history';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

import { SimpleComponent } from './code';

test('SimpleComponent', () => {
  const listenMock = jest.spyOn(history, 'listen');
  const unlistenMock = jest.fn();
  listenMock.mockReturnValue(unlistenMock);

  const component = mount(<SimpleComponent />);
  expect(component.state().pathStep).toBe(0);  // Success!

  const callback = listenMock.mock.calls[0][0];  // <= get the callback passed to history.listen

  callback({ pathname: '/second' });
  expect(component.state().pathStep).toBe(1);  // Success!

  callback({ pathname: '/' });
  expect(component.state().pathStep).toBe(0);  // Success!

  component.unmount();
  expect(unlistenMock).toHaveBeenCalled();  // Success!
})
```

Comment: ...and as a bonus it also verifies that the unlistener gets called

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was something like that.
On the very first mount it returns `/`, on the second mount it returns `/second` and from there it is back to the default state of 0(`/`)

```
jest.mock('./history', () => ({
  listen: jest
    .fn()
   .mockImplementationOnce(cb => {
      cb({ pathname: '/' });
    })
    .mockImplementationOnce(cb => {
      cb({ pathname: '/second' });
    }),
}));
```

And the test itself (to test both `/second` and `/` in 1 single test)

```
it('changes pathStep when called', () => {
    expect(component.state().pathStep).toBe(0);

    component = mount(<MyComponent />);

    expect(component.state().pathStep).toBe(1);

    component = mount(<MyComponent />);

    expect(component.state().pathStep).toBe(0);
  });
```

But to make the test work that I asked initially something like that will suffice:

```
jest.mock('./history', () => ({
  listen: cb => {
    cb({ pathname: '/second' });
  },
}));
```

I just had to pass a callback when mocking, so close to what I had before, but with some pairing managed to get it to work :)

Hope that it makes sense and will help somebody out in the future